# Growing organic tissue over a machine

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology, technology, robots

In a short story I created, humanity encounters a sentient and consciousness messenger that is alien in nature and origin. Upon further examination, it turns out that there is organic tissue grown over a mechanical skeleton and many other robotic systems.

The organic components include a flesh, organs, a brain, and muscle, and many other known organic components seen in living creatures

My question is

**how could one grow organic components over a robotic skeleton, and if possible, how could the nervous system grow to connect with the robotic system, as to better control said skeleton?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are [biocompatible materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biomaterial) which allow organic tissue to grow on an inorganic substrate.

> Biomaterials can be derived either from nature or synthesized in the laboratory using a variety of chemical approaches utilizing metallic components, polymers, ceramics or composite materials. They are often used and/or adapted for a medical application, and thus comprises whole or part of a living structure or biomedical device which performs, augments, or replaces a natural function. Such functions may be relatively passive, like being used for a heart valve, or may be bioactive with a more interactive functionality such as hydroxy-apatite coated hip implants. Biomaterials are also used every day in dental applications, surgery, and drug delivery. For example, a construct with impregnated pharmaceutical products can be placed into the body, which permits the prolonged release of a drug over an extended period of time. A biomaterial may also be an autograft, allograft or xenograft used as a transplant material.

And there are [interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain%E2%80%93computer_interface) between a neural system and an electronic system.

> A brain-computer interface (BCI), sometimes called a neural-control interface (NCI), mind-machine interface (MMI), direct neural interface (DNI), or brain-machine interface (BMI), is a direct communication pathway between an enhanced or wired brain and an external device.

Mix the two, and you got the answer to your question.